# Android radiobutton scroll bar showing when height is defined

Tags: android, radio-button

Inside `ScrollView` I have a LinearLayout where in turn it holds a `RadioButtonGroup` with `RadioButtons`. I have created a RadioButton with custom drawable (small sized radiobutton) like  in the first image, where I get scroll bar.

I tried to reduce the layout size by the following code

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams radio = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( 50, 50);
```

but still I am getting the scrollbar, how to remove the scroll.

[image]

```
        ScrollView outerScroll = new ScrollView(this);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams outerScrollLP = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( 
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);                

        outerScroll.setLayoutParams(outerScrollLP);

        LinearLayout outerLL = new LinearLayout(this);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams outerLLLP = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( 
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);            

        outerLL.setLayoutParams(outerLLLP);

        outerLL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);      
        //outerLL.setScrollBarStyle(LinearLayout.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
        outerLL.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg);
        //outerLL.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

        for (QuestionModol que : queBL.getQuestion(1)) {
            try {

                LinearLayout quesLL = new LinearLayout(this);
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams quesLP = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( 
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); 
                quesLP.setMargins(30, 10, 30, 5);
                //quesLL.setPadding(50, 30, 50, 10);
                quesLL.setLayoutParams(quesLP);
                quesLL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                quesLL.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.question_wrap);

                TextView queTV = new TextView(this);
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams queTVLP = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( 
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); 
                queTVLP.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10); 
                queTV.setLayoutParams(queTVLP);
                queTV.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
                queTV.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                queTV.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 15);
                queTV.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.questiontext);

                queTV.setText(que.getQuestion());
                queTV.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);                    

                quesLL.addView(queTV);

                // Create Radio Button

                RadioGroup optRadioGroup = new RadioGroup(this);

                RadioGroup.LayoutParams optRadioGroupLP = new RadioGroup.LayoutParams( 
                        RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                        RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); 
                optRadioGroupLP.setMargins(20, 0, 20, 10);                      
                optRadioGroup.setLayoutParams(optRadioGroupLP);
                optRadioGroup.setTag(que.getId());
                optRadioGroup.setOrientation(RadioGroup.VERTICAL);

                for(OptionsModel options : que.getOptions()) {
                    RadioButton rdoOptBut = new RadioButton(this);

                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams rdoOptButLP = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( 
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    rdoOptButLP.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;

                    // Hack code to remove the space b/w radio buttons 
                    //rdoOptBut.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);                      

                    rdoOptBut.setPadding(40, 0, 0, 0);                      
                    rdoOptBut.setId(options.getOptionId());
                    rdoOptBut.setLayoutParams(rdoOptButLP);
                    //rdoOptBut.setBackgroundResource(0);
                    rdoOptBut.setText(options.getOptionName());
                    rdoOptBut.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.custom_radiobutton);
                    //rdoOptBut.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 12);                    

                    optRadioGroup.addView(rdoOptBut);
                }

                quesLL.addView(optRadioGroup);

                outerLL.addView(quesLL);    

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
        }
        outerScroll.addView(outerLL);
```

Comment: Show us the code please.

Comment: if number of views shown in the layout is greater than layout size then scrollbar will always show.

Comment: But i am reducing the radiobutton height and with to 50 , but still its showing, if i remove the scroll bar means, the screen is not showing fully as some of the bottom screens gets truncated

Answer (score 0):

add this property to your scrollBar

```
           android:scrollbars="none"
```

Comment: Will work your code and get back, between i am constructing the above code dynamically

Comment: I think the layout is not refreshing, radiobutton is consuming its default default android radionbutton size. thats why when i reduce the layout of the custom radion button using LinearLayout.LayoutParams radio = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( 50, 50); its still scrollable.

Comment: Anu using your code i am able to prevent scroll bar, but i am not able to scroll the screen. Let me put the problem clearly.

Comment: Show me exactly what are you doing?

Comment: I have edited my question with code i am using to build the radiobutton. Please check

Comment: Got it fixed myself, for the linearlayout i have used a large background image, when removed the background image its working perfectly, Thank you all for the help and support.

Answer (score 0):

Got it fixed myself, for the linearlayout i have used a large background image, when removed the background image its working perfectly, Thank you all for the help and support.